# Can you create a new Q&A site following the Stack Exchange template?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

For new Q&A sites, does Stack Exchange offer their framework so that other teams can create new sites or is it all in-house?

Comment: If you're looking to host your own SO-like site, a clone might be of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Answer (score 10):

[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is where new sites (topics, as you put it) can be suggested.

There is a whole process of them going into private beta, public beta and graduating (or not).

The process is public and community driven - anyone can suggest a new site, so in many ways - nothing is "in-house" (very few exceptions - the original trilogy of Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault and [Ask Patents](http://patents.stackexchange.com), which was a special deal with the US office of patents).

Answer (score 2):

**If you are talking about making your own site outside the Stack Exchange network...**

Then yes, you are allowed as long as you:

- Make sure that you make it known that you have nothing to do with Stack Exchange.
- Do not use any logos or copyrighted material.
- Do not copy their exact HTML, CSS, Javascript, or any other code you can see.

I think I covered everything, but comment if I didn't.

You [can't copyright the *look and feel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_v._Borland) of a site or app. You can patent it, but as far as I know, SE doesn't have any patents (again, comment if I'm wrong).

**If you are talking about making another site inside of the Stack Exchange network...**

Then yes, you are still allowed :-).

Stack Exchange created [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) for just that: *so that users can propose new sites*. If you have a new site idea, go ahead and propose one on that site! From the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

```
 Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone. It's where groups
 of experts come together to build new Q&A sites that work just like
 Stack Overflow. Here you can:

     - Propose new Q&A sites. If you have an idea for an expert Q&A site,
       propose it here.
     - Get involved in the process. Help sites get off the ground by
       defining the types of questions that are wanted, recruiting a
       critical mass of experts, and committing to the site's success.
```